# jQuery Mobile: Adding to a SELECT in Code works only on Desktop browsers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

On desktop browsers (FF,IE,CR) I am able to add to a Select with this jQuery:

```
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
            output.push("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
        }
        $("#cboDay").append(output.join(' ')).selectmenu('refresh');
```

However, it does not work on iPhones or Androids.

For reference here's the Select:

```
<select name="cboDay" id="cboDay" data-native-menu="false"></select>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing **data-native-menu="false"** fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a **true** argument to force the refresh..

```
$("#cboDay").append(output.join(' ')).selectmenu('refresh', true);
```